# Site to Site VPN detection iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, networking, vpn

In our app, we need to detect if the user is connected to VPN network or not. When the VPN is configured on the iPhone or iPad, we are able to detect it using the reachability API kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection flag. However, how do we detect if the iPhone or iPad is connected to a site-to-site VPN. In this case, no configuration will be required on the client side as the VPN connection exists between two sites and the iPhone/iPad is just behind one of the site.
Please suggest if you know of any solution for this.

Comment: How do you distinguish a VPN from another network?

Comment: @Martin, one way is by looking at the src IP address block

Comment: @Mike: My question was rhetorical and your answer is probably the correct answer to the OPs question as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hetal, do you have a way to look at their source IP address?  If so, ensure you have a current list of your VPN address blocks and check to see whether the device source IP is in the block.